# How to create a dictionary with a generic struct as value?

Tags: swift, generics

I have this:

```
struct URLSessionUpload<T> where T: Decodable
{
    let url: URL
    let session: URLSession
    let task: URLSessionUploadTask
    let promise: Promise<T>
}
```

And want to do this:

```
private var _activeUploads = [URL: URLSessionUpload]()
```

But this is missing information about the generic type and shows error:

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

How do I specify the syntax to create the dictionary?

Comment: You can't. That is not what a generic is. A generic is not, of itself, a type. There is no such type as URLSessionUpload. There are only the infinite number of possible _resolved_ types, such as `URLSessionUpload<String>` etc. So URLSessionUpload cannot be the type of a dictionary's keys; there is no such type.

Comment: @matt ok thanks for the clarification! Though, the `URLSessionUpload ` is in this case the value, not the key. That's not going to work? Is there any other way around this conundrum without sacrificing the generic `promise`?

Comment: I meant "values", sorry.